# force:navigateToList is not workling in lightning out app

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am unable to redirect to listview of campaign in my component.

```
gotoList : function (component, event, helper) {
    alert('here in go to list');
var action = component.get("c.getListViews");
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    alert(state);
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var listviews = response.getReturnValue();
        alert('hello'+listviews);
        var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToList");
        navEvent.setParams({
            "listViewId": listviews.Id,
            "scope": "Campaign"
        });
        navEvent.fire();
    }
});
```

Apex code

```
@AuraEnabled
public static  ListView  getListViews() {
        List < ListView > listviews = [SELECT Id, Name FROM ListView WHERE SobjectType = 'Campaign'
                                       AND Name = 'Active Parent Campaigns'
                                      ];
        ListView lv = new ListView(id=listviews[0].id);
        system.debug('listview'+listviews);
        /*if (listviews.size() > 0) {
            return lv;
        } else {
            return null;
        }*/
        return lv;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.I dont think this works for lightning out.

Comment: this answer is correct - see documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToList.htm